# Wrong customer address in orders in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm posting this here rather than the Prestashop forums as attempts to post simply redirect to their homepage on all browsers.

Every week or so we receive 1-2 orders from around 50 which contain the an incorrect invoice and delivery address in the order details.  The address is of another customer.

I checked the ps_orders table and it looks as if occasionally the wrong id_address is saved for an order in the orders table.

This is very concerning as the customer also gets to see the wrong address on the front end and it also means we end up shipping out orders to the wrong address

I wonder if anyone else had experienced this or if anyone could suggest where to start looking for a cause for this?

Prestashop 1.6.0.14

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably comes from one of the carrier module in front-office, that is where you should start to look for.

Check your orders, is it always from the same carrier ? Or from a set of carrier that a module created and deals with ?
If yes, then there is a high change you have found the problem.

It also might come from a module who deal with the hook "ActionValidateOrder".

Comment: Thanks, I am using the standard carrier options that come with Prestashop and in regards t the hook, it's a good suggestion as to where the problem may be occurring but I've noticed the id_delivery_address changing in the cart before a customer places an order.  Having not yet found the cause of the problem it may instead worth me creating something which detects the problem and sets the correct ID instead.

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong in ps_address table. I have repaired/analyze ps_table. I have solved it by removing some ps_address table data.